# Hive question - Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY dept ORDER BY sum(salary))

Tags: hive

I am trying to understand how to use the rank() over(partition by ) in Apache Hive, but have problems getting the results I desire.

All the way at the bottom of the post is the dataset that I am working with.

What I am trying to do is to come up with a statement that will uniquely rank the departments according to the sum of salaries of the staff in that dept. However, I am getting rank 1 for all three dept.

Hope someone can advise me where I went wrong! thank you so much! :)

**What I want**

```
+-----------+--------+-----+
| dept_num  |  _c1   | rk  |
+-----------+--------+-----+
| 1000      | 24900  | 3   |
| 1001      | 17400  | 1   |
| 1002      | 20500  | 2   |
+-----------+--------+-----+
```

**What I am getting**

```
+-----------+--------+-----+
| dept_num  |  _c1   | rk  |
+-----------+--------+-----+
| 1000      | 24900  | 1   |
| 1001      | 17400  | 1   |
| 1002      | 20500  | 1   |
+-----------+--------+-----+
```

**The HiveQL statement I am using**

```
SELECT
dept_num, sum(salary),
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY dept_num ORDER BY sum(salary)) as rk
FROM employee_contract
GROUP BY dept_num;
```

**My dataset**

```
Michael|1000|100|5000|full|2014-01-29
Will|1000|101|4000|full|2013-10-02
Will|1000|101|4000|part|2014-10-02
Steven|1000|102|6400|part|2012-11-03
Lucy|1000|103|5500|full|2010-01-03
Lily|1001|104|5000|part|2014-11-29
Jess|1001|105|6000|part|2014-12-02
Mike|1001|106|6400|part|2013-11-03
Wei|1002|107|7000|part|2010-04-03
Yun|1002|108|5500|full|2014-01-29
Richard|1002|109|8000|full|2013-09-01
```

Comment: If you change the SUM() of `salary` to be calculated via a subquery, does it work as expected? Or same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below one,untested and let us know what you are getting

```
SELECT dept_num,TOTAL_SALARY,
rank() OVER (ORDER BY TOTAL_SALARY) as rk
FROM
(
SELECT
dept_num, sum(salary) as TOTAL_SALARY
FROM employee_contract
GROUP BY dept_num
)SUM_EMP
```

Comment: thank you so much! :)

yup, it works! :)

https://snag.gy/EIRZ8z.jpg

If you have some time, can you explain to me why my original HiveQL does not work or rather, how have I misinterpreted the way the PARTITION BY works? thank you!

Comment: PARTITION BY  is same/equivalent  as GROUP BY . Your HQL query will give the same result if dept_num is same . Here dept_num is different  for every row.Hence giving rk=1